# How do I pull all the events I have today Using the Google Calendar API in Pacific Time Zone

Tags: python-3.x, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to pull all my daily events from the start of the day to the end of the day using the google calendar API. I followed google's quickstart program using the API but it gives me the next 10 events and in UTC time zone with 0 offset. I want to only grab the events that day and in 'America/Los Angeles' time zone.

```
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z'
    print('Getting todays events')
    events_results = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=now,
                                        maxResults=10, singleEvents=True,
                                        orderBy='startTime').execute()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the following changes to your script:

```
today = datetime.datetime.today();
start = (datetime.datetime(today.year, today.month, today.day, 00, 00)).isoformat() + 'Z'
tomorrow = today + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
end =  (datetime.datetime(tomorrow.year, tomorrow.month, tomorrow.day, 00, 00)).isoformat() + 'Z'
print('Getting todays events')
events_results = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=start, timeMax=end, singleEvents=True, orderBy='startTime').execute()
```

If you want to retrieve **all** the events from today, you will have to use the `timeMin` and `timeMax` parameters. The `timeMin` will be set to today's date hour `00:00`, as for `timeMax` this will represent the end of this day - so tomorrow's date set with the `00:00` has been chosen.

Also, the `maxResults` parameter is not needed here since you want to retrieve all the events and not a limited number.

Please bear in mind that the dates provided for the `timeMin` and `timeMax` are both *exclusive* bounds and they must be an RFC3339 timestamp with mandatory time zone offset.

For future requests, you can also simulate them and test the parameters needed using the [Calendar API Reference](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list).

#### Reference

- [Calendar API Events: list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list);
- [Date and Time on the Internet: Timestamps](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339)
  .

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help and your time. However, I tried your solution and it is not working when I try to compile it.

Error Code:
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?timeMin=2020-11-09T00%3A00%3A00&timeMax=2020-11-10T00%3A00%3A00&singleEvents=true&alt=json returned "Bad Request">

Comment: @Matt, I have updated my answer. Also, please bear in mind that you might have to print the results if you want to see them. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I was about to ask how to adjust for timezone here as I got the wrong results using the code above but I figured it out - So I thought I'd say how I did it since people with the same problem might also end up here :)

Adjusting for time zones when requesting a list of events today:

```
today = dt.datetime.today()
start = (dt.datetime(today.year, today.month, today.day, 00, 00, 00)
        ).astimezone(tz_UTC).isoformat().removesuffix("+00:00")+'Z'
end = (dt.datetime(today.year, today.month, today.day, 23, 59, 59)
        ).astimezone(tz_UTC).isoformat().removesuffix("+00:00")+'Z'
```

Comment: tz_UTC comes  from:
import  pytz
tz_UTC = pytz.timezone('UTC')